# Angular ng-messages one among four field is required validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am using ng-messages directive for instant validation in my angular app. I have 2 phone number field and 2 email field. One among these four fields are required to submit the form. How to validate this? These four fields are generated dynamically by clicking on add phone or add email link.

Please go to this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/selvassn/rjqbpfkm

```
<form name="Form">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Phone1</label>
<input type = "text" ng-model="phone1" required>        
     <span class="help-block" 
     ng-show="Form.phone1.$error.required">Required</span>
 </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Phone2</label>
<input type = "text" ng-model="phone2" required>
     <span class="help-block" 
     ng-show="Form.phone2.$error.required">Required</span>
    </div>
         <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email1</label>
<input type = "text" ng-model="email1" required>
     <span class="help-block" 
     ng-show="Form.email1.$error.required">Required</span>
    </div>

         <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email21</label>
<input type = "text" ng-model="email2" required>
     <span class="help-block" 
     ng-show="Form.email2.$error.required">Required</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Add your code or create a JSFiddle please

Comment: HI Michelem, I have created a sample fiddle. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please include the code in the question by editing it as well. Just relying on external sites for relevant information is not encouraged.

Comment: This issue has been solved by using jquery validator